# Is $\mathbb{E}[f(\vec{X})g(\vec{X})] \ge \mathbb{E}[f(\vec{X})]\mathbb{E}[g(\vec{X})]$ for $f,g$ bounded, non-decreasing?

Tags: probability-theory, correlation

For a random variable $X$ and bounded and non-decreasing functions $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we have:
$$ \mathbb{E} [f(X) g(X)] \ge \mathbb{E} [f(X)] \mathbb{E} [g(X)]$$

In case I am given coordinate-wise non-decreasing (bounded) functions $f,g : \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}$ and a random vector $\vec{X}$, does:
$$ \mathbb{E} [f(\vec{X}) g(\vec{X})] \ge \mathbb{E} [f(\vec{X})] \mathbb{E} [g(\vec{X})]$$
hold true?

Comment: what does "non-decreasing" mean on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d \ge 2$?

Comment: @mathworker21 $\forall \vec{v}, \delta > 0, i \in [d],\ f(\vec{v}) \le f(\vec{v} + \delta e_i)$ where $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^d$ represents the standard basis vectors.

Comment: This isn't true in dimensions greater than one: e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^2$, taking $f(\vec{X}) = X_1$ and $g(\vec{X}) = X_2$, and letting $\vec{X}$ be $(-1, 1)$ or $(1, -1)$, each with probability $1/2$, we have $\mathbb{E}[f(\vec{X})] = \mathbb{E}[g(\vec{X})] = 0$ but $\mathbb{E}[f(\vec{X}) g(\vec{X})] = -1$.